# Grok problem - handling "SOME-TEXT" pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm stuck with grok.
Here is the code that i want to use in Kibana:

```
"1.1.1.1" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "21/Jul/2010:20:22:31 +0100" "GET /html/some_file.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 674347
```

How ever i can't pass through the "NULL-AUTH-USER". The IP address is handled, this is fine, but after that i'm stuck.
the code for grok that does not give back what i want:

```
%{IP:ipadd}%{WORD:notauusr}
```

The goal is to have something like this:

```
IP-address user date&time methode uri returncode size
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
"%{IPORHOST:clientip}" "%{USER}" "%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}" "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)
```

That is a modified version of `COMMONAPACHELOG`.

Checkout: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html and https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/httpd

There is also https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com which is a great tool to debug grok patterns.